# list errors shows in console but only one error shows in div

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, express-validator

I am using express-validator for form validation and using axios to send the data to to the server. Once the validation is done I send a response back. I can loop over the errors and display them all in console, one under another but in my error div where I want to show the errors to the user, it only shows one, instead of all of them like in console.

Controller:

```
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({error: errors.array()});
  }
```

Display errors to user:

```
  const errorLoop = error.response.data.error;
  for (const errMsg of errorLoop) {
    console.log(errMsg.msg);
    const showError = document.querySelector('.error');
    showError.classList.add("notification");
    showError.innerHTML = errMsg.msg;
  }
```

Comment: The `for` loop keeps overwriting the element with the contents of the last error.

Comment: Ah, of course. Doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the innerHTML for each error. Thus you are replacing it and will only ever see the last error.

Try this:

```
let errorMessages = ""
for(const errMsg of errorLoop){
    errorMessages += errMsg.msg + "<br>"
}
const showError = document.querySelector('.error')
showError.classList.add("notification")
showError.innerHTML = errorMessages
```

(The `<br>` will insert a new line for visual purposes)

Comment: `br` would be better (its HTML after all)

Comment: Right! Edited. :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I can only accept your answer in 8 minutes apparently

Comment: can also be rewritten as a one line: `document.querySelector('.error').innerHTML = errorLoop.map(item => { return item.msg; }).join('<br/>')`